# modify and append index for each of the list object returned to the angular controller

Tags: html, angularjs, spring-mvc

I am working on spring with angularjs. I am returning List as a return object from spring controller to angular controller.

For example my List size is 3,when printed in spring controller it is printed as below.

```
[org.com.pro.dto.MyDTO@6c0c233a,org.com.pro.dto.MyDTO@440233a,org.com.pro.dto.MyDTO@6e3c0c33n]
```

I am returning the above list object as JSON object to angular controller which when printed in browser console shown as below:

```
[{"name":"Sam","email":"sam@gmail.com","prod":"ipad","comments":"sam details"},
{"name":"john","email":"john@gmail.com","prod":"tv","comments":"john details"},
{"name":"dex","email":"dex@gmail.com","prod":"ipad","comments":"dex details"}]
```

I want to append index for each of the object returned from java controller to UI.
I want to return the list from spring controller to angular controller as below:

```
[{"index":0,"details":[{"name":"Sam","email":"sam@gmail.com","prod":"ipad","comments":"sam details"}]},
{"index":1,"details":[{"name":"john","email":"john@gmail.com","prod":"tv","comments":"john details"}]},
{"index":2,"details":[{"name":"dex","email":"dex@gmail.com","prod":"ipad","comments":"dex details"}]}]
```

How to modify my List to show as above by appending index for each of the object in the list. Any inputs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont need angularJS to solve this, just plain javascript.  Here are a few ways:

The original array

```
this.original = [{'name': 'Sam', 'email': 'sam@gmail.com', 'prod': 'ipad', 'comments': 'sam details'},
  {'name': 'john', 'email': 'john@gmail.com', 'prod': 'tv', 'comments': 'john details'},
  {'name': 'dex', 'email': 'dex@gmail.com', 'prod': 'ipad', 'comments': 'dex details'}];
```

Using [array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)

```
this.formatted = this.original.map( (value, index) => {
  return {
    index,
    details: [value],
  };
});
```

Using [array.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

```
this.formatted = [];
this.original.forEach( (value, index) => {
  this.formatted.push({
    index,
    details: [value],
  });
});
```

Using [for loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration)

```
this.formatted = [];
for (var i = 0; i < this.original.length; i++) {
  this.formatted.push({
    index: i,
    details: [this.original[i]],
  });
}
```